# Removing Tax Computation and Tax Labels on a condition

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-ee

When the company tax status is tax exempt

I want this to happen.
In the cart and checkout pages, and invoices:

- Remove the “incl. tax” items from the totals.
- Remove the “excl. tax” tags on remaining totals.
- Do not calculate tax on shipping cost.
- Do not calculate tax in order total.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated..